# How to focus a TextBox in a custom Dialog box

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

I have a WPF C# desktop app and pop up a custom Dialog Window. The Dialog Window has a TextBox that I would like to be focused on so as soon as it pops up, I can type something to it without moving and pointing my cursor.

The DialogBox is written as a class in code behind (not XAML) that goes like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CustomDialog dlg = new CustomDialog();
        dlg.ShowBox();  // after the dialog box pops up, focus on the textbox.
    }
}

public partial class CustomDialog : Window
{
    ....
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    ....
    public void ShowBox()
    {
       ....
       /* I want to focus on the tb as soon as CustomDialog.ShowBox() is called */
       ....
    }
}
```

I have tried all the following, but neither of them work:

```
1. tb.Focus();
2. Keyboard.Focus(tb);
3. FocusManager.SetIsFocusScope(tb, true);
4. Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)delegate
{
   tb.Focus();
});
```

**[ANSWER]**

Have to focus before showing the dialog:

```
tb.Focus();
window.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: tb.UpdateLayout(); tb.Focus(); try this

Comment: Are you able to see that Textbox in the UI?

Comment: of course I can see the TextBox

Comment: simple `tb.Focus()` works for me. Can you show us the code through which you are creating TB and adding it in the window + XAML?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the OnLoaded event and focus the text box in there:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnLoad();

   tb.Focus();
   tb.SelectAll();
}
```

Comment: @Faciu: there is on OnLoad event in the dialog box class.

Answer (score 1):

The text box is not focusing because the content of the Window has not been rendered yet.  Try focusing the text box using the CustomDialog class's Loaded event.  Connect an event handling method to the Loaded event, and in that method, focus the text box.

```
public partial class CustomDialog : Window
{
    ....
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    ....
    public void ShowBox()
    {
       ....
       this.Loaded += CustomDialog_Loaded;
       ....
    }
}

void CustomDialog_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tb.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add that I tried to "focus" a textbox in a popup dialog box and it was not working. 
I tried to focus the box before I called Form.ShowDialog();

None of the above worked.

Here is what worked for me:

```
//add textBox to form
myForm.Controls.Add(myTextBox);

//now select the textbox
myTextBox.Select();

//display the form
myForm.ShowDialog();
```

hope this helps!